# Hiding View in a Route Group in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a Route Group

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','use.ssl']], function () {

})
```

This Route Group is Order Process in E-Commerce Project. I want to learn that can i hide a view in this Route Group ?

I want to disable header messages for visitor in this pages of this group.

Comment: You mean like throwing a 404 error when a guess is trying to hit it?

Comment: If current url hits this route group i want to disable a part of view. I will show view like if(!$group)

Answer (score 0):

It might works if you do something like that inside a middleware

```
View::composer('*', function($view) {
    $view->with('group', true);
});
```

Then in your views you can test if `$group` exists and is true.

Comment: I want it only in this group. This means for every view ('*') For every view i disabled. I want only in this route group.

Answer (score 0):

I feel i couldn't find best solution. But i solved problem in a different way.

```
view()->share('orderProcess', FALSE);
```

with this code i'm sharing $orderProcess variable with all views.

```
@if(!$orderProcess)
//A part of my view
@endif
```

This code will show the part of my view when $orderProcess if FALSE. Now in every page i'm showing my view.

In order process cart, orderAddress, orderPayment, orderResult i'm sending (orderProcess, TRUE) value to view. And it removes the part of my view.

This works but i want find better solutions.